# GenerateConditions in Sum gives incorrect answer

Tags: bugs, summation

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.0**

---

Why does

```
Sum[Exp[I z n]/n, {n, Infinity}, GenerateConditions->True]
```

return

```
-Log[1-E^(I z)]
```

even though the sum only converges if $\text{Im}[z] \geq 0$ and $z$ is not an integer multiple of $2 \pi$?

```
SumConvergence[Exp[I z n]/n, n]
```

gives the correct answer.

*Mathematica* 9.0.1 on Mac OS X.

Comment: What's the question supposed to be here?

Comment: @J.M. It's a bug report; if someone has this issue, wonders why `Sum` and `SumConvergence` are giving different results, and searches these key words, they can find out why here.  I didn't add the "bugs" tag because only high-ups in the community are supposed to do that, but hopefully someone will.

Comment: I know it's supposed to be a bug report; the point is that this is a Q&A site, so at the very least, make it look like a question. :)

Comment: You can, if you wish, make this a question by asking for other workarounds.

Comment: On my system (Mac) , it was fixed in version 10.0

Comment: @BobHanlon Really?  Odd, I never tried it on v10.0 but Wolfram emailed me specifically saying that it was fixed in v11.0.

Comment: (I know that only high-up members of the community are supposed to add the "bugs" tag, but since Wolfram Inc. personally told me that it was a bug, I've gone ahead and added the tag myself.)

Comment: "since Wolfram Inc. personally told me that it was a bug" - yes, in that case, adding the tag yourself is defensible. :)

Comment: With version 8.0.4 I get the output shown in the question. Versions 10.4.1 and 11.0.0 produce the correct output on my system (Windows 7 x64). Looks like the bug was indeed fixed in version 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filed a bug report with Wolfram about this issue.  They e-mailed me upon the release of Mathematica 11.0 and told me that the issue has been fixed in that release.

Answer (score 1):

THIS IS AN EXTENDED COMMENT

Version 10.0 gives the same result as version 11.0

```
$Version

(*  "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)"  *)

Sum[Exp[I z n]/n, {n, Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> True]

(*  ConditionalExpression[
   -Log[1 - E^(I*z)], 
   E^Im[z] >= 1 && E^(I*z) != 1]  *)

SumConvergence[Exp[I z n]/n, n]

(*  E^Im[z] >= 1 && E^(I*z) != 1  *)

$Version

(*  "11.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)"  *)

Sum[Exp[I z n]/n, {n, Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> True]

(*  ConditionalExpression[
   -Log[1 - E^(I*z)], 
   E^Im[z] >= 1 && E^(I*z) != 1]  *)

SumConvergence[Exp[I z n]/n, n]

(*  E^Im[z] >= 1 && E^(I*z) != 1  *)
```

Comment: Maybe they fixed it in 10.0 then.  But 9.0 definitely gave the wrong answer - I filed the bug report in January 2014 and they said they'd fix it in a future version.  No idea why they waited until now and then told me they'd fixed it in v11.0.

Comment: @tparker Just a guess: may be they indeed have fixed another `Sum`-related bug in version 11 and notified everyone who wasn't notified before? A muddle in the bugs database...